# Java - Deselect all checkboxes inside a checkbox group

Tags: java, checkbox

Evening, i'd like to know how to in java deselect all checkboxes inside a checkbox group? I know that there's a trick by using a checkbox with the label "None" but that option doesn't suit my needs.

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Swing program? Do you mean JCheckBoxes? And are they all added to one ButtonGroup object? If so, simply call the ButtonGroup method `clearSelection()`. If not, and really regardless, please improve your very incomplete question.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [`ButtonGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html), you'll note a few methods of interest...

### You Could...

Enumerate through the elements of the group...

```
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
Enumeration<AbstractButton> elements = bg.getElements();
while (elements.hasMoreElements()) {
    AbstractButton btn = elements.nextElement();
    btn.setSelected(false);
}
```

### Or You Could...

Simply use the `clearSelection` method...

```
bg.clearSelection();
```

Depending on your needs...